# Show images in a dropdown menu when creating a new form

Tags: sharepoint-online, sharepoint-designer, javascript, custom-list, custom-form

Is it possible to create a picture library as a reference to display the images in another list. So when someone goes to the list and creates a new item, they'd be able to select the image thumbnail from a dropdown menu of the new form.

Any help would be appreciated.

Answer (score 4):

As [several](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2965971/how-to-add-images-in-select-list) [questions](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1697996/image-in-select-element) and [answers](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2524953/how-can-i-put-an-image-into-select) over on StackOverflow point out, not without an additional Javascript widget to convert the `<select>` control of the drop-down into something else.  According to the HTML standard, it is not possible to put `<img>` elements inside `<option>` elements.